# React + Jest :- Babel Error Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am trying to run some tests with Jest, and the project is throwing these errors:-

```
 FAIL  src/imports/components/Forms/__tests__/FilterForm.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In \node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js

      at createDescriptor (../../../AppData/Roaming/nvm/v10.18.1/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

my package.json looks like this:-

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.4",
    "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "6.20.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.11",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.20.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.16.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.12",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0",
    "coveralls": "2.11.15",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "enzyme": "3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15.4": "1.0.5",
    "eslint": "3.12.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-watch": "2.1.14",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "mockdate": "2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "1.2.1",
    "prompt": "1.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.4",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "sinon": "4.1.2",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.13.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5"
  },
```

and the babel config file looks like this:-

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "latest",
        "react-hmre"
      ],
      "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        ["latest", {
          "es2015": {
            "modules": false
          }
        }]
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-constant-elements",
        "transform-react-remove-prop-types"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "latest"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the FilterForm.test.jsx imports:-

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15.4';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FilterForm from '../FilterForm';
import TextField from '../../Fields/Text';
```

From what I was researching, it seems that I have an old babel iteration?  If it is, how can I upgrade to the newest?  I tried removing babel and re-installing it but did not work.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide `src/imports/components/Forms/__tests__/FilterForm.test.jsx` as well, just for easier debugging?

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac just the imports right?  Or the whole file?

Comment: I think snippet of where and how you import it, and how it is exported from that file would be enough

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac I added the imports, is that enough?

Comment: Looks good, is this only happening when unit testing? Or is it happening when you run `npm start` as well? Maybe its a Jest environment issue

Comment: with npm start, the project runs correctly, however I get different test fails, and they are taking a lot of time to run.  BTW am new to React testing, just got this project over to fix the tests

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac with npm start I get this:-  Test Suites: 28 failed, 42 passed, 70 total
Tests:       71 failed, 300 passed, 371 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        229.581s
Ran all test suites.

Answer (score 1):

Jest 24 [dropped support for Babel 6](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel). You can either upgrade to Babel 7 or stay on the the Jest 23.x series